# JOIN with WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
Select 
    Tbl1.field1, 
    count (*) as total
from Tbl1
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 on Tbl1.geoid=Tbl2.field1
LEFT JOIN Tbl3 L on Tbl2.Field2 = L.Field2
and Tbl2.[Current Original Listing Date] >= Convert(datetime, '2017-08-01' )
GROUP BY Tbl1.field1
```

Tbl1.field1 has a static list I need to output the entirety regardless the count of Tbl3.

my problem is that as I tighten up the date in the where clause, I'm expecting more zero's in the count column, but when the count goes to zero, the record goes away.

what am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: you may need to show your sample data on those tables and expected result

Comment: Are you running that exact query and seeing no results or are you running it with a where clause? Where clauses and left joins may produce results similar to an inner join (thus eliminating some rows), but the query as you've currently written it shouldn't do that.

Comment: Please add sql to create your tables and mock data.

Comment: Since you are left joining, and you are counting (*), you should only get additional rows from the joins regardless of the dates in the join condition. The more you tighten up the date range, the less rows you'll get form tbl3, but you wont impact rows from tbl1 or tbl2.

Comment: ok.  thanks much for the attention.  Please allow me to set all that up and redo the question with all that you guys are asking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the date restriction within the join of the table it references:

```
SELECT
    Tbl1.field1, 
    count (*) as total
FROM Tbl1
LEFT JOIN Tbl2 ON Tbl1.geoid = Tbl2.field1
              AND Tbl2.[Current Original Listing Date] >= '20170801'
LEFT JOIN Tbl3 L on Tbl2.Field2 = L.Field2
GROUP BY Tbl1.field1
```

Not sure why you are joining tbl3 but if it is needed then include it.

Note if using CONVERT() to datetime from a literal then you should specify the style number otherwise you are relying on server settings. Otherwise the safest date literal in SQL Server is YYYYMMDD and then you don't need to use convert or cast.